# How can we solve the "freshest questions get looked at only" problem?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

There is an observable usage pattern with StackOverflow that people monitor the newest questions and answer only them. So after the initial flurry there is very little activity on a question. Generally that is fine, but some types of questions have answers that change over time (what framework is available for X, for example), or might have better answers if got the attention of the newer members of the community who weren't around when it was first asked.

The problem with asking a new question is that it very quickly gets closed as a duplicate. So perhaps there should be a way to resurrect old questions. The most obvious way would be to have a question closed as a duplicate cause the duplicate to become new again (with perhaps some exceptions based on number of votes on answers, or the number of answers).

Another might to allow someone with sufficient reputation to resurrect a question.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Editors have bumped up lots of older Java and Swing questions, which are the main tags I follow.  I look at the questions tagged with my tags, but they are usually answered already.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious solution to this problem is to get rid of the Newest Questions view. Now I'm saying we should do that but it's clear to me that's what most people look at. New questions get the most vote activity. Far fewer people look at the home page (but they do).

Or perhaps make Newest Questions a higher-rep privilege?

Comment: I think this would lead to a positive-feedback system, where most of the rep is gained from getting in a good early answer, and only those with a lot of rep can get that head start. There's no way someone working their way from the bottom to really get ahead.

Comment: What if "active" was left-most within the questions tabs, rather than "newest"? Would that help?

Answer (score 2):

> The most obvious way would be to have a question closed as a duplicate cause the duplicate to become new again

With the current implementation of bumping, then this would cause two questions to be bumped on each close.

> Another might to allow someone with sufficient reputation to resurrect a question.

The question isn't gone, just back of the pile. And if it's a common issue it's going to get a lot of views through google. (which amounts for 90% of the site's traffic)

Answer (score 1):

There was another recent suggestion concerning bumping topics and I had the idea of charging reputation to bump a topic back to the top of the active list. Granted this won't do a whole if people monitor the new questions only list. But I will say this, if I am going to watch the new questions list, I want to see new questions, not resurrected old ones. That's why I watch the new questions list and not the active list.

You aren't really going to be able to legislate how someone uses the site and what questions they care to look at.

Comment: I think this is an excellent idea. Questions could be bumped (at a cost) by anyone with an interest in bringing the question back into the mainstream. It's better than some indiscriminate behavior to recycle older messages.

Answer (score 0):

If the new question gets closed as a duplicate, then maybe you should do some due dilligence first and search the site for your question?  When you start typing a new question, SO even suggests some potential duplicate questions for you to look at before you post your question.  I'm not speaking for the creators, but it appears the object here is to provide answers, not hand-hold people who ask the questions.  It is the user's responsibility to act within the guidelines, or at least read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

EDIT: When I re-read that, I think I came off "snippy".  That wasn't my intention, so please don't be offended.